# Get <a href="https://www.google.se/"> adress width html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm having this html:

```
<div class="table-wrapper" style='display: block;'>
<table id="tableSearchArticle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#">Article</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">art.nr.</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Detail.ashx/121308" target="_blank">
                    Apple
                </a>
            </td>
            <td><span class="mobile-only">Tillverkarens art.nr:</span>11068</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Detail.ashx/124494" target="_blank">
                   Banana
                </a>
            </td>
            <td><span class="mobile-only">Tillverkarens art.nr:</span>11405</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my method that is supposed to get all a href adresses in the table. But Now I only get a list of Article name. My list returns Apple, Banana. I want to return a list of the a href - http-adresses. How can I do that?

```
        public List<string> GetListOfHrefs()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.dabas.com/mypages/search.aspx?typ=FP&sosokord=laggen");
        var xpath = "//table[@id='tableSearchArticle']/tbody/tr/td[1]//@href";
        var listOfGtins = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
            .Select(td => td.InnerText.Replace("GTIN:", "")).ToList();
        return listOfGtins;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems in your XPath - `href` is attribute of `a` element, not of `td` element, and you cannot select attributes with XPath - you should select elements:

```
var xpath = "//table[@id='tableSearchArticle']/tbody/tr/td/a[@href]";
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
               .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Output:

```
[
  "http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Detail.ashx/121308",
  "http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Detail.ashx/124494"
]
```

Comment: I'm having some problem with this. The page I'm trying to get HTML from is this one: http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Detail.ashx/121308
But if you look at the sourcecode, it for the most part contains javascript. Is there any change I can reach the HTML in it and use the html Agility Pack features to solve it? @SergeyBerezovskiy